# Call Rails Controller from Console (passing credentials and/or session ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

> > app.get '/namespace/controller'

works, but how can I:

1. Pass the credentials to a secure controller.
2. Pass the SESSIONID for a previously authenticated user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `app` object takes care of the session for you, so you don't need to worry about handling the session id manually.  So, you just login, then access other pages that depend on the session being set:

```
app.post app.login_path, :username => "username", :password => "password"
app.get app.other_path
```

You can also inspect the response and session after any request, eg.:

```
app.response.redirect_url
app.session[:user_id]       # assumes your login process uses the `user_id` key in your session
```

If you want, you can create a file called `.irbrc` in your `$HOME` directory, combining some of these ideas with something like this in it:

```
if Rails
  def login
    app.post app.login_path, :username => "username", :password => "password"
    "Logged in with user_id: #{app.session[:user_id]}"
  end
end
```

Then, in your Rails console you can just type `login` to issue that method, and it will return the string showing the value of the `user_id` session element.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I tried this and am using AuthLogic for authentication (with "email" as the login_field) but couldn't get it to work. I even tried to hardcode the "create" method in UserSessionsController with the email/password and the session appeared to get created (though I didn't see it persisted in the DB). And sure enough, the subsequent "get" call failed (most likely because of a non-existent session in the DB store). Am I missing something?

Comment: Never mind, the view was missing (and I didn't need this particular view for a UI-based login). It works just fine now. Thanks much!